# How to show array of Strings in GridView for CardView

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm trying to show an array of strings as items in a GridView but it's not working. Any idea on what Java code should be used to display them? Also, in the RecyclerView item class, I'm not sure if an `Array` or `String` type should be used in this scenario.

**Fragment class**

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private MyRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    static final String[] frenchVowels = new String[]{
            "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"
    };


    public MyFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();
        assert v != null;

        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(getContext(), getHeader(), getListItems());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    public RecyclerViewHeader getHeader()
    {
        return new RecyclerViewHeader();
    }

    public List<MyRecyclerViewItem> getListItems() {
        List<MyRecyclerViewItem> rvItems = new ArrayList<>();

        MyRecyclerViewItem item = new MyRecyclerViewItem();
        item.setTitle("French vowels");
        item.setDescription("¿What goes here?");
//        for (String frVowels : frenchVowels) {
//            adapter.addAdapterItem(new MyFragment.AdapterItem(frVowels));
//        }
        rvItems.add(item);

        return rvItems;
    }
}
```

**RecyclerView item class**

```
public class MyRecyclerViewItem {
    private String title;
    private String description;

    public MyRecyclerViewItem(){}

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

//    public Array getDescription() {
//        return description;
//    }
//
//    public void setDescription(Array description) {
//        this.description = description;
//    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**Expected result**

[image]

**Current CardView (collapsed)**

[image]

**Current CardView (expanded)**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I see you're using a LinearLayoutManager. You'll want to change that to a GridLayoutManager. You can try this code:

```
//Set GridLayoutManager
    int gridColumnCount = 2
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, gridColumnCount));
```

The amount of columns is controlled by the number in the "gridColumnCount".

Comment: please delete your answer. A solution has been found.

Comment: If it gets to -3, I'll think about it.